# any way to remove doubles in uv editor across different uv islands?

Tags: uv

I was exporting uv-mapped model back and forth and at some point it should have messed up my uv map. It is aligned properly with all vertexes where they should be, but every face became a separate island.

it looks ok when you don`t touch it:

[image: image-1]

but when I use pack islands, this happens:

[image: uv map packed]

is there any way to restore a proper uv map?

P.S. 
some islands are mirrored and placed directly above each other

Edit: the file itself

[image]

Comment: Not quite sure, so I won't put this as an answer, but you can select the face on your mesh. This will also select the island on your UV map. That way you can simply drag it to where you want it. Btw, what's wrong with your 1st UV map? it's fully textureable...?

Comment: @Mr Zak, that merges all selected vertices into one. which would simply destroy the uv map altogether

Comment: @FreemoX,it is indeed texturable but i need proper islands for zbrush.
it's normal map baking relies on islands and this uv map creates an unusable bake.
Also I'm afraid even if i manage to deal with it in zbrush it will mess up something else later.

Comment: i meant that "weld" would merge all selected vertices into one. Remove doubles on the other hand only works within one island. in my case every face became an island of its own

Comment: @Mr Zak, afaik remove doubles in 3d viewport will merge the vertices but not their uv representations. In my model the actual vertices are connected but in the uv layout all faces are separated. When i use remove doubles in uv view, the selected vertices are merged into one single vertex. when i use remove doubles in 3d view nothing happens (as there are no double vertices).

Comment: I uploaded the file to the question. Thanks for the link. Though i had to delete one of the images because of reputation restrictions

Comment: Trying to reproduce the problem i was able to track down who messed up the uv in the first place. It was zBrush's UV Master. When I copied uv's from another .obj with same topology it shattered uv islands, strangely leaving some of them intact. To make sure you don't find yourself with same problem check the UV's every time after copying. Trying this several times lead to same effect so it`s not just random error.

Comment: Honestly I don't really have idea how to ccorrect that quickly other than reunwrapping. If [selecting one vertex on the mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRtMy.gif) it appears that vertex is presented in several UV islands. Weld or Remove doubles won't remove "double" vertices here as they aren't double. Some of the isllands are stacked on top of each other..Thanks for the info about UV Master, this can help at least to show when did this appear and now I know even more how powerful is it.

Comment: just to clarify: this uv is not generated by uv master. It's blender unwrap with custom seams and heavily adjusted by hand. ZBrush does not handle low poly unwrapping very well (at least not for me).

Comment: After some experiments i was able to find a way to properly transfer uv from blender to ZBrush, though its overcomplicated to say the least: 1) export from blender to fbx. 2) import fbx to zbrush as a new tool 3) export this tool from zbrush as .Goz 4) go to your tool, select lowest subdiv level and freeze subdivisions 5) import .Goz over your tool 5) copy uv in uv-master 6) unfreeze subdivision 7) paste uv from uv-master.

Comment: In this case the uv is copied and pasted over the same mesh and works fine. The problem seems to be caused by copying uv from another mesh and having same topology does not guarantee it will work as expected.

Comment: Also be carefull with .obj format. It works fine if your uv does not have small details. But if it does .obj can mess them up because of low prevision vertex positions. (in my example it messed up fingernails uv)